# Getting a list of files in a directory with extensions

Tags: android

Am trying to retrieve all the file names alongwith extension from external storage to my app. Already I tried but it is showing file size= 0" while i am debugging but at the same time it is showing file names also. Please try to suggest me.

```
private File root;
private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
private LinearLayout view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

    //getting SDcard root path
    root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    getfile(root);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(fileList.get(i).getName());
        textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getName());

        if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
        view.addView(textView);
    }

}

public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);

            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif"))

                {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

}

Comment: This code is working fine, I tested it on emulator with API 23. Check whether you have requested READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the directory to the file list in your getfiles() method. So that it showing file size is 0.
Do a small change, just remove that `fileList.add(listFile[i]);` from your getfiles() method. Hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you its working but am unable to open sub folders from that list